# Calcular com Javascript e retornar no html

Tags: javascript, html5, formulário, return, matemática

Então pessoal, eu preciso só pegar uma informação do HTML e voltar o resultado do calculo, porém não consegui.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculadora</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var calculadora = function (){
            var pessoas = form1.pessoas.value;
            var myCalc = pessoas*0,2;
            parent.document.getElementById("calc").Text = myCalc;
        }
        </script>
        </head>
    <body>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    Pessoas
    <form name="form1">
        <input type="Text" name="pessoas"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="calcular" onclick="return calculadora()">
    </form>
Resposta:
        <input type="Text" id="calc"  readonly ><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `0,2` troque por `0.2`. De onde veio esse "parent" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Três problemas a corrigir:

**a)** Em JavaScript numeros com parte decimal têm um ponto e não uma virgula.

**b)** valores de inputs são strings, texto. Tens de converter esse valor num numero, com por exemplo `Number()` ou `parseFloat()`.

Corrige a linha

```
var myCalc = pessoas*0,2;
```

para

```
var myCalc = Number(pessoas) * 0.2;
```

**c)** Para mudar o valor de um `input` tens de usar `.value`e não `.Text`

**jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f7yL1rah/**

Comment: Valeu cara resolveu aqui

Comment: @lipesmile ótimo! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Infelizmente não tenho 15 de reputação, tenho 14 senão já teria marcado

Comment: @lipesmile para marcar não precisas de reputação, só para votar. Deves clicar num simbolo que está a cinzento, logo por baixo de onde se vota na resposta.

Comment: @lipesmile: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/129